# How can i do convert an integer value to a real value in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I don't know how to coding a 4-byte integer value to a 4-byte real.
in C Language ...
I want to do something like this:
`float value = *((float*)&intValue))`

I would like to complete the code following....

```
  real function castingInt32_to_real( intValue )

  implicit none
  integer,intent(in) :: intValue
  
  !
  ! if intValue == 1065353216(0x3f800000)  Its means 1.0 on Intel.

  !I want to do following....
  castingInt32_to_real <-- 1.0
  
  end function
```

Comment: Or just use the `Real` intrinsic function, rather than rewrite it less generally as you seem to be doing.

Comment: Note also Integer is not guaranteed to be 32 bits, and I have used compilers where this has been the case

Comment: Neither is C `int` guaranteed to be 32 bits. What Fortran does require is that `integer` is the same storage size as `real` and `logical`.

Comment: Hi all.
Everyone, I apologize for the lack of explanation below.
The development environment is Windows11 (64bit) with ifort.
Question was based on the assumption that integer=4 bytes and real=4 bytes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a BOZ entity, you can convert that to real with the `real` intrinsic subprogram.  Consider,

```
program main
   real x
   x = real(z'3f800000', kind(1.e0))
   print *,x
end program main
```

which gives with gfortran

```
% gfortran -o z a.f90
% ./z
   1.00000000
```

As an addendum, you can also use the `transfer` intrinsic subprogram.

```
program main
   real x
   x = transfer(1065353216,x)
   print *,x
end program main
```

The above essentially does a bit-wise transfer.